# Offline mode no images loading in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

In offline mode, images are not getting loaded. So button with image not visible in offline mode. Is there any alt option available for button with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen on a real device.  On simulator it can because you're turned off the Chrome network traffic and it can no longer load images from the worklight server.